# how manage the scrollToIndex method with angular's material virtual scroll

Tags: angular, angular-material

Could you tell me how manage the scrollToIndex (virtuall scroll) if my list is not loaded during the ngAfterViewInit lifehook? I need to call the scroll to the index when I m redirect from an other page, so in the ts file. So my goal is to point to the right index when the page is loaded

```
@ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport) viewport: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;
ngOnInit() {
...
this.getData(index);
}

getData(index){
return this.service.get().subscribe(data => {
this.fullDatasource = data;
this.selectedIndex = this.fullDatasource.findIndex(value => value.id === index);
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
this.viewport.scrollToIndex(this.selectedIndex);
}
```

Nothing happens, if I call the method in the ngAfterViewInit. Many many thnaks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could try running the `scrollToIndex` in a `setTimeout` function, i think this triggers another round of change detection, by then your list could be loaded. Another way to archive this is to use the `ChangeDetectorRef`, see the [official docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) for details on how this works.

Or trigger the scroll manually in the subscription of the `getData` method instead of `AfterViewInit`.

Comment: Many thanks Johannes, it does work with a set timeout in the getData but I feel like I'm doing something wrong. Will it work if I have a very large dataset (100K) for example?

Comment: I think it would still work, because you just trigger one additional change detection round, no matter how big the data is.
Another way to trigger another change detection round would be using the `ChangeDetectorRef` and calling `detectChanges`.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if virtual scroll makes sense in this case. Concerning the timeout, is it good to put it in knowing that the virtual scroll is designed to handle very large dataset ?